# Making a CORS request in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, cors, jsfiddle

I am trying to simulate ping a website in JSFiddle i.e. if a website (say www.google.com) is available then show the status as "Up", otherwise "Down"

AJAX won't work as it will be a CORS request.
I tried to do it using Image source trick but it failed (updated code).

<strike>JSFiddle set the source of image to "https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/www.google.com" instead of "www.google.com"</strike>

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rohitkandhal/xus5e6p9/)

```js
var sites = {
  google: {
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    id: "googleStatus"
  },
  dummy: {
    url: "http://www.dummysitealphabeta2.com",
    id: "dummySiteStatus"
  }
}

pingSite(sites.google); // Should update status to "Up"
pingSite(sites.dummy); // Should update status to "Down"

// ping site using image trick wiz. Add source of site to image
// and add handler to image onload or onerror
function pingSite(site) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = site.url;
  image.onload = function() {
    console.log("loading loaded for " + site.url + "successfully");
  }

  image.onerror = function() {
    console.log("Image loading failed for " + site.url);
  }

}

// Using AJAX - Won't work because of CORS
function getStatus(site) {
  $.ajax(site.url).done(function() {
    // Http 200 OK
    $(site.id).html("Up");
  }).fail(function() {
    // HTTP 401,
    $(site.id).html("Down");
  });
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Google</td>
    <td id="googleStatus"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dummy Site</td>
    <td id="dummySiteStatus"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to do it using Image source trick but JSFiddle set the source of image to "`https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/www.google.com`" instead of "www.google.com"

That's because `www.google.com` is a **relative** URL that is local to the **current path**.

JS Fiddle is setting nothing. It is your code.

If you want to access a different hostname, then you need either an absolute URL (e.g. starting with `http://` or `https://`) or a scheme relative URL (starting with `//`).